# Granting user permissions using sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /dir/ectory/

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, chown

I am following this tutorial: [How To Set Up Apache Virtual Hosts on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

I get an error on: **Step Two — Grant Permissions** which states the following:

> Now we have the directory structure for our files, but they are owned
> by our root user. If we want our regular user to be able to modify
> files in our web directories, we can change the ownership by doing
> this:
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/public_html
> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/test.com/public_html
> ```
>
> The $USER variable will take the value of the user you are currently
> logged in as when you press "ENTER". By doing this, our regular user
> now owns the public_html subdirectories where we will be storing our
> content.
>
> We should also modify our permissions a little bit to ensure that read
> access is permitted to the general web directory and all of the files
> and folders it contains so that pages can be served correctly:
>
> ```
> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
> ```
>
> Your web server should now have the permissions it needs to serve
> content, and your user should be able to create content within the
> necessary folders.

I typed in the line in Command Line: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /dir/ectory/`
and then I get an error which says: `chown: invalid group: ‘developer:developer’`

I have searched and found no working solutions to this problem.

I am using [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr). I'm both new to Ubuntu and Stack Overflow, so I apologise for any stupid mistakes that I mightn't made while asking the question. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I tried your suggestion jgb and I still got the error however the username in the error message has changed. Initially it was 'chown: invalid group: ‘developer:developer’' but after trying your suggestion it changed to 'chown: invalid user: ‘paulashbourne:developer’'

Comment: Sorry. Syntax is: `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /dir/ectory`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I managed to fix it using `sudo chown -R username:group /dir/ect/ory` where username and group were replaced by my username and its group.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This worked:

```
sudo chown -R username:usergroup /var/www/nameofdirectory
```

Comment: But none of "username", "usergroup", and "nameofdirectory" are literal?